# How to center printed text *all* kinds of consoles?

Tags: python, text

I know that to print center-aligned text in python, you can use a very simple function : `.center(width)`. However I do have a problem with this function : it is horrible when you use multiple editors and consoles. I often switch between VS Code and Sublime Text and my friends with who I work use python IDLE and finally my teacher uses CMD. So the width is completely different from one computer to another.

I googled this a little bit and what I found is the function `os.get_terminal_size()`. However, does not work on IDLE and Sublime Text...

Isn't there any solution to do just like in Word where your text is centered no matter what the console and no matter what the width?

Comment: No, there isn't one.

Comment: yes, that is it: both idle and sublime text are environments that do not try to emulate a terminal enough to have an "width". Just pick a minimum common width, like 80chars, and use that.